# Pinning a file to that it appears in the beginning in a folder

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, files

I am using Ubuntu (Linux mint). There is a mouse option, if I right-click on a file, I can then choose to pin a file (inside its folder), so that whatever file arranging method (alphabetical, by-date, etc) the pinned file will always appear at the beginning of the folder. I looked online to find out if this can be done from command-line, couldn't find anything. Also `pin` is not a command in Linux. Any ideas? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I haven't heard of a way to do this in a shell terminal. It may just be a feature of that particular desktop environment. I mean, technically, there's no reason you couldn't look at the source code to see how the DE is doing that and then modify the `ls` command to do the same, but I'm not aware of anything built-in.

Comment: Any feature like that would be specific to the program in question, though in GUI, some programs might use a common dialog for choosing files to open or save (though on Linux systems, I'd expect those to be provided by the toolkit, not the wider OS as such, unlike e.g. on macOS where pretty much everything uses the same file open dialog). While an implementation of `ls` could support something like that, I doubt you're going to find one, since it would involve saving the pins somewhere, and another tool for setting them etc. Stuff that a regular `ls` has no need at all for.

Comment: I suppose the usual workaround would be to rename the file into something that makes it appear first in a list without any software changes, perhaps something like `!README.TXT`, but the sorting order also depends on the locale...

Comment: You could write a script in ~/bin that overrides ls to list certain files in a directory before others. One solution would be to have a .pinned file or directory in each directory that has "pinned" files. The script would list the files in "pinned" first, then list the rest in the normal manner. You would need to make sure your ~/bin comes before /usr/bin in the PATH variable, usually done in .profile (or the equivalent config for the shell you use).

Comment: By the way, I'm not recommending overriding ls in the way I posted above, but it is a possibility. Or you could write a script with a different name that calls ls and does what I suggested above.

Answer (score 2):

as you said, pin is not a command and this functionality doesn't work in command line.
In other words, Linux files have no attributes for this.

I think your file manager, maybe Nautilus in case of Mint?! uses an upper layer to indicate these desired files.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I found a way to manipulate the Linuxmint file manager (Nemo) to get what I want; would add it as an answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

The command is

`gio set /path/to/file/ metadata::pinned-to-top true`

If one is in the folder containing the file this command wouldn't seem to take effect, but after refreshing the folder one can see the change.

I wonder how to refresh using command line, couldn't find anything on google. Maybe someone can answer in the comments, I am reluctant to ask another question.